# What is the outer measure of the union of uncountably many sets of measure 0.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I know that the union of countably many sets of measure 0 has measure 0. How about the case of uncountably many of them?

Comment: Singleton sets have measure zero. Every set is a union of singletons.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of *any Lebesgue measure* by taking uncountable unions. For example, suppose that we wanted a set of measure $1$. Consider the following set:
$$
\bigcup_{0\leq x \leq 1} \{x\}
$$
Each set $\{x\}$ has measure $0$, but the uncountable union of these sets such that $0\leq x\leq 1$ is the closed interval $[0,1]$, which has measure $1$.

So uncountable unions of measure $0$ sets could be anything!